# Silex: Dynamic routing scaling code base

Tags: php, symfony, silex

My routing definition looks like this (using [this](https://igor.io/2012/11/09/scaling-silex.html) as reference to have better order in the code):

```
$app->get('/actor/{id}', 'TMDb\Controller\TMDbController::actorAction');
```

And this is how my controller looks like:

```
class TMDbController {
    public function actorAction(Request $request, Application $app) { ... }
}
```

And it worked, but I haven't found the way to get in my action controller the `id` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
public function actorAction($id, Request $request, Application $app)
```

Silex (Symfony2's HttpFoundation, actually) passes the named parameters from the url to the function's argument with the same name.

You should also check out the [parameter converters](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#route-variables-converters) so your controller gets the object (or array) the id refers to, and not the plain id.